# How does filter works for Struct property in spark dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, aws-glue

I want to filter out some records from a dataframe using filter method. I have a address Array of Struct, which I am comparing with a column value. I am using below code:

```
entityJoinB_df.filter(col("addressstructm.streetName").cast(StringType) =!= (col("streetName")))
```

I want to remove the element from address struct based on comparision. The sample schema is as below:

```
root
 |-- apartmentnumber: string (nullable = true)
 |-- streetName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- streetName2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- fullName: string (nullable = false)
 |-- address: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- streetName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- streetName2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- buildingName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
 |-- isActive: boolean (nullable = false)
```

But its not working. What can be the problem. Can anyone help?

Sample Input:

```
[
{
"apartmentnumber":  122,
"streetName": "ABC ABC",
"streetName2": "CBD",
"fullName": "MR. X"
"address": [{
            "streetName": "ABC ABC",
            "streetName2": "CBD",
            "buildingName": "ONE",
            "city":"NY"
           },
           {
            "streetName": "XYZ ABC",
            "streetName2": "XCB",
            "buildingName": "ONE",
            "city":"NY"
           }]
}
]
```

Sample Output:

```
{
"apartmentnumber":  122,
"streetName": "ABC ABC",
"streetName2": "CBD",
"fullName": "MR. X"
"address": [
           {
            "streetName": "XYZ ABC",
            "streetName2": "XCB",
            "buildingName": "ONE",
            "city":"NY"
           }]
}
]
```

Thanks,
Upen

Comment: please also paste sample input and output

Comment: @QuickSilver, I have updated the query

Comment: what is `addressstructm` ? Its no where in schema

Comment: It is the address array of struct renamed as   addressstructm. I have two tables from where I am getting address. One table has only primary address and other table Primary+secondary. When I am joining these two tables array is having duplicate Primary address. So i want to filter the address if have same field values

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem can be solved by modifying the filter expression to

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    entityJoinB_df.withColumn("address",
      expr("filter(addressstructm.address, x-> ( x.streetName != streetName AND x.streetName != 'Secondary' ) )"))
```

assuming `addressstructm` is the alias of your Dataframe

Below is the sample struct similar to yours

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object StructParsin {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = Constant.getSparkSess
    import spark.implicits._

    val df = List(
      Apartment(Array(Element("ABC ABC","123"),Element("XYZ ABC","123")),"ABC ABC"),
      Apartment(Array(Element("DEF","123"),Element("DEF1","123")),"XYZ")
    )
      .toDF

    df.printSchema()
    df.withColumn("newAddress",
      expr("filter(address, x -> ( x.streetName != streetName AND x.streetName != 'Secondary' ))"))
      .show()
  }
}

case class Element (streetName: String)

case class Apartment(address: Array[Element],streetName:String)
```

Comment: Hi.. Its not working.. getting the same array still:"address": [
     {
            "streetName": "605 THOMAS1 AVE APT 1",
            "streetName2": "  ",
            "buildingName": "",
            "city": "LYNDHURST"
            "order": "Primary"
        },
        {
            "streetName": "605 THOMAS1 AVE APT 1",
            "streetName2": "  ",
            "buildingName": "",
            "city": "LYNDHURST",
            "order": "Secondary"
        }
    ]

Comment: @upenkas please check now

Comment: The above solution is removing both elements from the struct. I needed to remove only secondary one

Comment: check for typos because same input works for the above code @upenkas

Comment: Sorry I checked again,Its removing the primary one. I need to remove the matching secondar address. Can u please let me know how to incorporate 'AND' condition in expr() because using this way entity_join_c2.toDF().withColumn("address",expr("""filter(address, x-> (x.streetName != streetName && x.order!="Secondary"))""")) Its giving parseexception in gluejob. Thanks @QuickSilver

Comment: @upenkas updated the ans with your requested epxression

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
scala>

entityJoinB_df
.withColumn("address",
    array_except($"address",
        array($"address"(array_position($"address.streetName",$"streetName")-1))
    )
)
.show(false)


+-------------------------+---------------+--------+----------+-----------+
|address                  |apartmentnumber|fullName|streetName|streetName2|
+-------------------------+---------------+--------+----------+-----------+
|[[ONE, NY, XYZ ABC, XCB]]|122            |MR. X   |ABC ABC   |CBD        |
+-------------------------+---------------+--------+----------+-----------+
```

Comment: can you check now ??